# Creating/saving database objects in django ModelForm save method

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-1.6

I have model form `JobPosting` with a custom field `location_query` which I use to generate data for a model field `location`. In doing this I need to create an `Address` object for the `location` field and save it to the database. I believe the correct time to save this object is  within an overloaded `save` method of `JobPosting`.

While the new `Address` object is created and saved, it does not get saved as the value of the `JobPosting`'s `location` field, and I'm not sure why.

Below is a simplified example:

```
class Address(Model):
    pass

class JobPosting(Model):
    location = ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)

class JobPostingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    location_query = forms.CharField(max_length=256)

    class Meta:
        model = JobPosting
        fields = (
            'location_query',
            'location', # hidden field
        }

    def clean_location(self):
        data = self.data.get('location_query')
        addr = Address()
        # do some stuff here to dump data into addr
        return addr

    def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.instance.location and not self.instance.location.uuid :
            self.instance.location.save()
        instance = super(JobPostingForm, self).save(commit=commit, *args, **kwargs)
        return instance
```

The obnoxious thing is that the code above results in the JobPosting being saved with location as `None`, but if I save the address in the `clean_location` function it works correctly. Obviously I don't want to save a database object in a clean function, but I'm pulling my hair out trying to figure out why this is.

Comment: `instance = super(AttorneyJobPostingForm, self).save(commit=commit, *args, **kwargs)` what is this? `AttorneyJobPostingForm` ?

Comment: oops. I forgot to edit that when simplifying

Comment: ok.. and now tell me what is it `self.instance`?

Comment: as I understand it, ModelForm uses instance for the underlying model instance.

Comment: Did you check this? What do you have in self.instance?

Comment: Yes, did check. It is an object of type JobPosting. Typically I think it's used when passing in the model to the Form for use with views that edit the model object.

Comment: `instance = super(JobPostingForm, self).save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)` this should be a first line in `save()` method. Next remove `self` from `self.instance`. In the end `instance.save()` `return instance`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66506/discussion-between-catskul-and-slawek).

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set the `location_id` manually. I had been assuming since I'd seen it happen in all other cases, that the `<field>_id` member was automatically filled in on save, that it would happen here. I'm not sure why it isn't but adding `instance.location_id = instance.location.uuid` after saving the location did the trick.

I also moved the instance.location setting code to after the super save (as suggested by @Sławek) as self.instance will not always exist if it hasn't been passed in at form creation time.

The new code looks something like this:

```
def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = super(JobPostingForm, self).save(commit=commit, *args, **kwargs)
    if instance.location and not instance.location.uuid :
        instance.location.save()
        instance.location_id = instance.location.uuid

    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: In this situation you are saving two times `instance`. change it to `commit=False`. Show me Address() model.